# Is there a name for arrows of the type a -> a (in Haskell notation) in category theory?

Tags: haskell, category-theory

Whats the name of arrows in category theory that have this type:

```
a -> a
```

"From a type(?) to another object of the same type"

Or maybe there's no particular name for them?

In other words: Is there a name for the set of all arrows that go from any type a to the same type a? Examples of arrows (functions?) of that set:

```
\x->x+x   :: Int->Int
\x-> "hello, " ++ x :: String -> String
...
```

**Edit**

@leftaroundabout says that I'm using OO definition of object for category theory, which is wrong. Therefore, what I'm really asking is: "In category theory, in a category  what is the name for a morphism from some object O of  to O itself?"

Comment: My guess is "identity".

Comment: An [endomorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endomorphism)?

Comment: @mvw: I guess the question isn't entirely precise, but I interpret it to include for example the map x ↦ 2x from the reals to the reals (in, say, the category of sets and maps of sets)… Can you clarify, Lay González?

Comment: @gspr: Yes, from reals to reals is an example.

Comment: @LayGonzález: What I meant to ask was: Is the map x ↦ 2x (for example from the reals to the reals, but that isn't the point of my question) an example of what you mean? If not, then endomorphism isn't the right answer.

Comment: @gspr Are you saying that I am asking (in other words): "What is the name of the set of arrows that go from a type to the same type?" If yes, then you're right. map x->2x would be a subset of this set, right? And all arrows that map reals to reals would be a bigger subset, right?

Comment: I suppose what would be most relevant is whether you mean `∀ a . a -> a` (that's what this signature would mean in Haskell) or just `T -> T` for some particular type `T`.

Comment: @leftaroundabout: Wouldn't that just distinguish between "endomorphisms of some object X in the category C" and "all endomorphisms in the category C"? mvw's comment about identities made me think I'm misreading Lay's question more deeply than this distinction. I'm reading the question as "what do we call morphisms from an object to itself in category theory?"

Comment: @gspr The arrow of an object to itself is the identity for each type. \x->(x+x) is the type of functions I'm looking for, "give me an integer and I return a (possibly different) integer"

Comment: @gspr: well, I suppose a polymorphic signature like `∀ a . a -> a` doesn't even make sense in a general category. In a _small category_ , this signature means _functions from objects of  to endomorphisms of these objects_. In **Hask**, this is certainly not the same as the collection of all endomorphisms, for `id` is indeed the only such polymorphic function you can define (without ⟂).

Comment: @leftaroundabout: Agreed… but I'm still not sure exactly what OP wants :-)

Comment: @leftaroundabout: I rephrased the question and added some examples.

Comment: Note that you seem to confuse OO objects with category-theory objects. "To another object of the same type" doesn't make sense, since the objects of **Hask** _are_ types. The correct phrasing of your question would simply be "In category theory, in a category  what is the name for a morphism from some object _O_ of  to _O_ itself?" As said by gspr, those are endomorphisms.

Comment: @leftaronudabout rephrased again. Thanks.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If I'm correct in interpreting your question as *"what do we call morphisms from an object to itself in category theory?"*, then the word you're looking for is *[endomorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endomorphism)*.

Comment: wouldn't that be only the identity arrows?

Comment: No. The map x ↦ 2x (for example as a map from the integers to the integers) is an endomorphism (of the integers) in (for example) the category of sets.

Comment: @LayGonzález There can even exist other [nontrivial automorphisms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automorphism) besides `id`. Also, _endo_ is quite a generic prefix, you'll frequently read about _endofunctors_, and I've even heard about _endo-natural transformations_.

Answer (score 6):

The word you're looking for, as many others have said, is "endomorphism."  But in a more concrete note it's worth mentioning here the [`Endo` type in `Data.Monoid`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Data-Monoid.html#t%3aEndo):

```
data Endo a = Endo { appEndo :: a -> a }

instance Monoid (Endo a) where
    mempty = Endo id
    Endo f `mappend` Endo g = Endo (f . g)
```

This type is sometimes useful.  For example, [as Brent Yorgey explains, folds are made of monoids](http://byorgey.wordpress.com/2012/11/05/foldr-is-made-of-monoids/):

```
import Data.Monoid

foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
foldr f z xs = appEndo (mconcat (map (Endo . f) xs)) z

foldl :: (b -> a -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
foldl f z xs = appEndo (mconcat (map (Endo . flip f) (reverse xs))) z
```

So, since monoids are associative, oftentimes folds can be parallelized (with a divide-and-conquer strategy) by first rewriting them in terms of `Endo`, and then replacing the specific `Endo b` for that fold with some more concrete type that allows for some of the work to be done at each `mappend` step.